# How to delete duplicate baseline in lightweight-chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, lightweight-charts

I have straight horizontal line in my chart which of I want to get rid. I don't know why it's appeared.
If someone coult assist me with getting rid of that line i woult highly appreciate it, thank you in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCaMs.png)

```
chartReference.current = createChart(chartContainerReference.current!, {
      width,
      height,
      layout: {
      grid: {
        horzLines: {
          color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
          visible: false
        },
        vertLines: {
          color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
          visible: false
        }
      },
      crosshair: {
        horzLine: {
          visible: false,
          labelVisible: false
        },
        vertLine: {
          visible: true,
          style: 0,
          width: 2,
          labelVisible: false
        }
      },
      localization: {
        priceFormatter: (value: number) => formattedNumber(value, true)
      }
    })
    const chart = chartReference.current

    seriesReference.current = chart.addAreaSeries({
          topColor: chartColors[activeNetwork].area.topColor,
          bottomColor: chartColors[activeNetwork].area.bottomColor,
          lineColor: chartColors[activeNetwork].area.topColor,
          crosshairMarkerBorderColor: 'white',
          lineWidth: 2
```

I expect to not have that extra base line (in green rectangle)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.